# How To Disable (or Remove) "All Posts, Published, and Trash" in Dashboard Posts

Tags: posts, dashboard

I have been looking for ways to completely remove the All, Published, and Trash webpages for USERS ***other than the me, the Administrator***.

So the scenario for me is: I have registered users (which I would like to assign with the roles of authors, contributors, etc). Now, when they log in to my website and access the Posts area, I wish for them not to see these three links (All, Published, Trash).

I have tried using the jquery function, which is basically the same as display: none, but I don't think it's the optimal choice. I know there's better ways for me to do this.

I did try using plugins, such as Member and Adminimize, among other things, but I can't find the right one.

I hope there's someone out there who can help me. Thanks in advance.

[image: Remove All, Published, and Trash]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `WP_Posts_List_Table` class extends `WP_List_Table` and within the `WP_List_Table::views()` method we have the following dynamic *views* filter:

```
/**
 * Filter the list of available list table views.
 *
 * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$this->screen->id`, refers
 * to the ID of the current screen, usually a string.
 *
 * @since 3.5.0
 *
 * @param array $views An array of available list table views.
 */
 $views = apply_filters( "views_{$this->screen->id}", $views );
```

So we can use the generated `views_edit-post` filter to adjust the views of the *post list table*.

### Example:

Let's remove the *all*, *publish*, *future*, *sticky*, *draft*, *pending* and *trash* for non-admins (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
/**
 * Remove the 'all', 'publish', 'future', 'sticky', 'draft', 'pending', 'trash' 
 * views for non-admins
 */
add_filter( 'views_edit-post', function( $views )
{
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return $views;

    $remove_views = [ 'all','publish','future','sticky','draft','pending','trash' ];

    foreach( (array) $remove_views as $view )
    {
        if( isset( $views[$view] ) )
            unset( $views[$view] );
    }
    return $views;
} );
```

where you can modify the `$remove_views` to your needs. Another approach would be to only pick up *mine* and only return that view.

Then we could try to force the *mine* view further with:

```
/**
 * Force the 'mine' view on the 'edit-post' screen
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( 
           is_admin() 
        && $q->is_main_query() 
        && 'edit-post' === get_current_screen()->id 
        && ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' )
    )
        $q->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() ); 
} );
```

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

Comment: You're welcome and hopefully you can adjust it to your needs @chest_nut

Comment: Yes, thank you! I surely will. I'm still learning and it's amazing that you guys are here to help us out. :) @birgire

Comment: For custom post types, the filter is views_edit-my_custom_post_type. Refer to the Admin Screen Reference here https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Admin_Screen_Reference

Comment: I think its better to use [wp_count_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_count_posts/), check the `$type` that is passed, and unset the desired indexes.

Comment: How will that remove the "All" view, as asked by OP? There are also two `wp_count_posts()` calls in the list table, so one would have to look closer into that to make sure there are no side effects (avoid counting irregularities), as the other instance seems to be affecting the total items count in only some cases. More context is needed than only `$type`, as the function can be used everywhere. Plugins can also add their own `wp_count_posts()` calls, e.g. as a bubble count in admin menu that runs on the same page. WooCommerce does this for eg the shop_order post type.

Answer (score 2):

Those statuses are turned from `get_available_post_statuses()`, which in turn gets its values from `wp_count_posts()`.

`wp_count_posts()` passes it's values through the `wp_count_posts` filter.  So you can tap into that and hijack what gets returned.

Try this:

```
function _dbdb_wp_count_posts( $counts, $type, $perm ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if( 'edit.php' !== $pagenow ){
        return $counts;
    }

    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ){
        return $counts;
    }

    $_counts = new stdClass();
    foreach ( $counts as $status => $count ){
        $_counts->$status = '';
    }

    return $_counts;
}
add_filter('wp_count_posts', '_dbdb_wp_count_posts', 99, 3 );
```

What this does is check if we're on the `edit.php` page in the Admin,and if not, just return the counts.

Then it checks if the current user can manage site options, which only an Administrator can.  If the current user can, all counts are returned.

If you get past this check, it assumes you're not an Administrator, so it resets all counts to `0`, effectively removing the status links.

**Note:** the "all" and "mine" status links are hard-coded in the `get_views()` method of the `WP_Posts_List_Table` Class and aren't filterable.

I quickly tested this on my dev server, first signing in as an Admin, and then as an Author.  It worked as expected, but be sure to test thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The Published and Trash links are gone. However, I still have the All link, even though its counter is at zero, the link is still active and it brings me to the list of all the posts. Hmm... I'm not sure if that's what's appearing on your end as well?

Comment: Yes.  I mentioned that in my answer.  The "all" link and the "mine" are hard-coded, not passed through s filter like the others.  They can't be removed, only hidden.

Comment: I see, thank you @darrinb . Guess I will just hide the All link then. Thanks a lot. I'm still new on WP development I really am wanting to learn as much as I can. Anyway, thanks again, really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem!  Glad I could help!  If this worked for you, be sure to accept the answer so others know.

Answer (score 0):

Return only "Mine" status

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-{your-cpt}', function( $views ) {           
   if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
      return $views;
   }
   return array_filter( $views, fn( $i ) => 'mine' === $i, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY );
} );
```