# How To Remove “All, Publish, Draft and Expired” in Events Dashboard

Tags: plugins, admin, dashboard, events

I have been looking for ways to completely remove the All, Publish, Draft and Expired events for USERS other than the me, the Administrator.

So the scenario for me is: I have registered users. When they log in to my website and access the Events area (WP Eventmanager), I wish for them not to see these  links (All, Published, Draft and Expired).

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, take a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/224253).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with the following plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/