# How to find the file path in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

According to client requirments, we need to some modifications and Add a new status menu before trash.
But I am not able to find the file path. My question is this, in which file this text exist. I want to know file path where i can make changes. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The path to which file?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do you are definitely trying to do it a wrong way. Start from reading [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224159/how-to-disable-or-remove-all-posts-published-and-trash-in-dashboard-posts) question/answer.